# Java naming file

Tags: java

I'm trying to rename the file that my program is outputting, but no matter what name i'm trying to change it to, it is stuck with the first name i listed which is "output.txt". I rename it to output1. txt and it still gives me output.txt could someone help with this?

```
public class Assignment2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    if (args.length < 1) {
        System.out.println("Sample command: java Assignment2 input.txt");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output1.txt");
        int i = 1;

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Matrix #" + i);
            processMatrix(scanner, fw);
            i++;
            System.out.println("");
            fw.write(System.lineSeparator());  
        }

        scanner.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Assignment2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect you've made a mistake in your testing.  `new FileWriter("output1.txt")` will not create a file called "output.txt".

Comment: i'm trying to get it to output to output1.txt but it still output a file name output.txt

Comment: You probably have a compile error or something in your code that results in stale code to be executed. Also make sure to re-compile your code after making changes. Java is no scripting language and you need to compile your code after each change to take effect.

Comment: When I run your code, it creates output1.txt as expected.  How, exactly, are you running your code, and how are you making sure it's creating the wrong file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see there is nothing wrong with your code.

So the only problem I can think of, is you are not building/compiling the file and therefore you are stuck on a older version of that file.

I don't know what technology stack you are using, but a still way to check this since its java, hopefully you got the environment variables configures. Just go to your terminal, to the file folder and:

javac Assignment2.java
java Assignment2

You can also tell me which IDE you are using, or how you are building/running your code.

Comment: i'm using Eclipse. so where should i go to clear out the system so that i can get my code to run again?